# Media Queries doesn't seems to be working when deployed on Heroku

Tags: html, css, vue.js, heroku, media-queries

I've CSS media queries which works perfectly over localhost. But when I deploy it on Heroku, media queries doesn't work. I have also included the metatag.

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

And I'm using the `@media queries` like this:

```
   @media only screen and (max-width: 900px){}
```

I'm using the VUEJS framework and using the CSS in the VUE file.

```
<style>
   (code)
</style>
```

Now, it works fine on **Heroku only** when I use `!important` with every property in media queries. Is there any solution to that. 
Is there any solution with out using !important.